# Hide control depending on url

Tags: jquery

My url is of the format http://www.xyz.com/DisplayPost.php?postid=200

I want to detect if the url has "postid=250" in it and hide a div called divOne

How can I do it using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is stored in the `window.location.search` variable, so you can scan that:

```
/[?&]postid=250(&|$)/.test(window.location.search)
```

Comment: where did the other reply go??
Nick, I want to start by hiding the div and then display it only when postid is not equal to 250. 

Should I set visibility:hidden or visibility:collapse and howto change the logic

Comment: Another point is that the content of the div gets populated with a script. It's basically an advertisement that shows up using javascript

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might be going about this the hard way. Why not just have the empty, which can be effectively the same thing as invisible, then just let it show when it is populated by the script?